# Error on 'gcloud app deploy' for large flask project

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, flask, gcloud

I'm trying to deploy a flask API onto google app engine. The project is large due to having a 8 neural network models. When trying to deploy, it say there are over 30 000 files to upload to google cloud storage. Deployment runs for 5 hours then crashes with many repeated errors:

`MaxRetrialsException: last_result=(None, (<type 'exceptions.IOError'>, IOError(24, 'Too many open files'), <traceback object at 0x120e07830>)), last_retrial=3, time_passed_ms=61927,time_to_wait=0`

`MaxRetrialsException: last_result=(None, (<class 'httplib2.python2.httplib2.ServerNotFoundError'>, ServerNotFoundError('Unable to find the server at www.googleapis.com',), <traceback object at 0x1171f0bd8>)), last_retrial=3, time_passed_ms=93989,time_to_wait=0`

`OperationalError: unable to open database file`

(3 lines repeated a lot)

Answer (score 1):

App Engine deployments are [limited to 10,000 files per version](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Deployments) and as such, deployments where the there is a need to upload over that threshold will fail.

However, there are some workarounds to this issue. For instance, you can split your app into multiple modules (now called services) so as to stagger the number of files uploaded.

Another possible workaround is that in the event where most of your files are static, consider storing it and serving it from [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/) or even from [Cloud CDN](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. It was my mistake, I forgot to add .venv to my .cloudignore file and now it is reduced to only 40 files. However after it uploads all the files, it starts "Updating service" and fails after the 10m timeout. I tried setting the config to be longer than 10 mins but it still fails with the same 10m timeout error. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: No problem. When this type of issue occurs, there is most likely an issue regarding the configuration of the app.yaml, such as App Engine not being able to start up the application correctly and finally timing out because it failed the readiness health-check or an invalid key-value pair, etc.. Could you provide a snippet of the app,yaml file?